# Vue CLI error creating new project (npm error)

Tags: vue.js, npm, vue-cli

Please help me on this. I can't create a new Vue CLI project. It previously works good! Now not working...

**Vue CLI v4.2.3**

> ✨  Creating project in /Web develop/Vue Projects/new.
>
> Initializing git repository...
>
> ⚙️  Installing CLI plugins. This might take a while...
>
> npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...loader":"~0.8.0","js-'
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>
> npm ERR!     /Users/Malaka/.npm/_logs/2020-03-25T06_30_10_474Z-debug.log
>    ERROR  command failed: npm install --loglevel error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems a cache error

run

```
npm cache clean --force
```

then try create the project again

Answer (score 0):

That's weird. I'd just try re-installing the Vue cli package.

There is a deprecated `vue-cli` package, it could be you have that installed rather than the official one `@vue/cli`.

Either way just uninstall it with

```
npm uninstall [your-vue-cli-package] -g
```

Then re-install it again.

```
npm install @vue/cli -g
```

Comment: Thank you for reply its works when i run this command   npm cache clean --force   its was cache...

Answer (score 0):

lets try this

```
$ sudo npm uninstall -g vue

$ sudo npm uninstall -g vue-cli

$ sudo npm uninstall -g @vue/cli

$ sudo npm cache clean --force

$ sudo npm install -g vue

$ sudo npm install -g @vue/cli
```

Answer (score 0):

problem log:

```
npm ERR! code ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
npm ERR! network Socket timeout
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\DraKoan\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-04-19T17_09_34_388Z-debug-0.log
 ERROR  Error: command failed: npm install --loglevel error --legacy-peer-deps
Error: command failed: npm install --loglevel error --legacy-peer-deps
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\DraKoan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\lib\util\executeCommand.js:138:16)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:526:28)
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\DraKoan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:34:29)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1092:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
```

Solve:

check proxy at config

```
npm config edit
npm config --global edit
```

clean and set proxy

```
npm config set proxy null
npm config set proxy false
```